# Passing data to tableView in Objective-C and learning about object scope

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I've been working with straight objective-c for a few weeks now, and lately I've been building out tiny cocoa mac apps to get started on that front. I'm now trying to figure out a couple quirks I've run into with IB and Cocoa, and I'm fairly certain both are related to object scope.

Below is my file in question, nothing really special going on with the other imports. What is odd here is that my **list** variable will log two different arrays even though I'm targeting the class instance with **self**. Maybe I'm using this keyword wrong, or maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but either way, my **list** var is definitely tracked independently by both the update and create methods.

My second issue is that my **create** method doesn't work if it's not triggered by a IBAction. Currently I've chained it to a separate button to get my table view to reload with the **update** method. Why is it that my **create** method wont work if I set it to *void* and just call that method directly from another controller?

```
#import "Lesson_14AppDelegate.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "Transaction.h"

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize list, transaction;

- (id) init
{   
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        Transaction *aTransaction = [[Transaction alloc] init];
        transaction = aTransaction;
        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView *) tableView 
    {
    return [self.list count];
}

- (id) tableView: (NSTableView *) tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *) tableColumn row: (NSInteger) row 
{
    Transaction *t = [self.list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    return [t valueForKey:identifier];
}

- (IBAction) update: (id) sender
{   
    [self.list addObject: self.transaction];
    [tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"list: %@", self.list);  
}

- (IBAction) create: (float) amount : (NSString *) description
{               
    [self.list addObject: description]; 
    [tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"list: %@", self.list);      
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [self.list release];
    [self.transaction release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why does your `update` method perform `addObject`?  Shouldn't that be modifying the contents of the array rather than adding to it?

Comment: Logically yes.. I killed my architecture in the name of resolving this bug temporarily however since my button click is attached to update and my create method is called programmatically.

Comment: I cannot see why the logging of `list` would differ between calls; your code looks OK to me.

Comment: If you'd be so kind and want to take a look at the full app it is here: http://www.4shared.com/zip/2IqjHopr/Budget_App.html when you use it you can fill out amount and description (make sure to blur or click out of each field for it to set the vars) and then you'll see the add button and update button trigger create and update respectively and create different arrays